# What is the best and fastest way to check if the image is valid in PHP?

Tags: php, image

What is the best and fastest way to check if the image is valid in PHP ?
I need it to be able to check GIF, JPG as well as PNG images.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Checking if the image file is in the correct format?

Comment: @MichałWojciechowski to prevent end user from uploading harmful file, disgusing as image file

Answer (score 49):

[exif_imagetype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) is a better solution.

This method is faster than using getimagesize. To quote [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) "The return value is the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but exif_imagetype() is much faster."

```
if(exif_imagetype('path/to/image.jpg')) {
    // your image is valid
}
```

**Update:**

After reading that getimagesize can be unreliable I tried to find some more info on what file types can give false positives but could not find any more info so performed a brief test (using `exif_imagetype`):

```
PowerPoint-survey-results.pptx - N
LRMonoPhase4.wav               - N
TestWordDoc.doc                - N
drop.avi                       - N
test.dll                       - N
raw_data_sample.sav            - N
text.txt                       - N
Excel-survey-results.xlsx      - N
pdf-test.pdf                   - N
simplepie-1.5.zip              - N
Word-survey-results.docx       - N
centaur_1.mpg                  - N
Test.svg                       - N
multipage_tif_example.tif      - Y
200.gif                        - Y
Test.png                       - Y
test.jpg                       - Y
```

I realise this is not exhaustive however at least show that with common file types the results are as expected.

Comment: Of course this only works when EXIF extension is enabled. In my case it's not the case and I have no control over this :(

Comment: since exif_imagetype returns same as getimagesize and getimagesize is supposingly "unreliable", anyone can confirm exif_imagetyle is safe to use in production to determine file is jpeg/png?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial exif_imagetype is NOT safe to use. You should also check extension of the file, or at least set it yourself when uploading. the exit data could be spoofed and you only have to insert a few bytes into your file to make it "look" like a png type

Comment: Sadly if you run the function on a truncated png for example the return value is still the constant for the png, even if the file is not a valid png.

Answer (score 9):

As recommended by the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

"Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image.Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead."

Here is an example:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = finfo_file($finfo, "test.jpg");

if (isset($type) && in_array($type, array("image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"))) {
    echo 'This is an image file';
} else {
    echo 'Not an image :(';
}
```

Comment: This method is insecure and could be exploited. An attacker could spoof the MIME type, and upload files with a .php extension

Answer (score 4):

I guess [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("path/to/image.jpg");

if (isset($type) && in_array($type, array(
    IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Read documentation: Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 3):

exif_imagetype is much faster than getimagesize and doesn't use gd-Lib (leaving a leaner mem footprint)

```
function isImage($pathToFile)
{
  if( false === exif_imagetype($pathToFile) )
   return FALSE;

   return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this function... it checks urls too

```
function isImage($url){
   $params = array('http' => array(
                'method' => 'HEAD'
             ));
   $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
   $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
   if (!$fp) 
      return false;  // Problem with url

  $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
  if ($meta === false){
      fclose($fp);
      return false;  // Problem reading data from url
  }
 }
```